# Объясните суть атомарных операций

Tags: c++, многопоточность, атомарность

Вопрос по поводу атомарных операций...
Берем, допустим, инкремент, выполняется следующее:

```
1)грузим в регистр значение переменной
2)инкрементируем
3)выгружаем из регистра в память
```

Если начинаем делать это из разных потоков, то можем старое значение считывать, это понятно...

Однако, с помощью какой магии атомарные типы из разных потоков позволяют такое проворачивать без ошибок? что значит атомарный тип? это свойство определенного типа или это можно гарантировать для любого типа?
Ну и код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
//std::atomic<long long> i{1};
//std::atomic<long long> ii{2};
long long i = 1;
long long ii = 2;

std::thread t1([&](){ i++; i--; ii++; });
std::thread t2([&](){ i++; i--; ii++; });
std::thread t3([&](){ i++; i--; ii++; });
std::thread t4([&](){ i++; i--; ii++; });

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();

std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

std::cout<<i<<" "<<ii;
}
```

почему что для атомарных типов, что для неатомарных выводится всегда 1 6... не должно же быть такого

Comment: Вы сделайте хоть немного подольше - у вас же мгновенное выполнение без каких бы то ни было переключений!

Comment: @Harry, подольше сделать конкретно что?

Comment: См. мой ответ. Потоки сделать подлиннее. За какие-то наносекунды переключения потоков не будет!

Comment: *однако, с помощью какой магии атомарные типы из разных потоков позволяют такое проворачивать без ошибок?* - синхронизированный доступ к памяти

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не дали ни единого шанса :) - такой короткий поток успеет все сделать и завершиться без переключения.

Например,

```
    long long i = 1;
    long long ii = 2;

    std::thread t1([&](){ for(int q = 0; q < 1000000; ++q){ i++; i--; ii++;}});
    std::thread t2([&](){ for(int q = 0; q < 1000000; ++q){ i++; i--; ii++;}});
    std::thread t3([&](){ for(int q = 0; q < 1000000; ++q){ i++; i--; ii++;}});
    std::thread t4([&](){ for(int q = 0; q < 1000000; ++q){ i++; i--; ii++;}});

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); - это нафиг не нужно!!!

    std::cout<<i<<" "<<ii << std::endl;
}
```

дает при компиляции VC++2015 и выполнении на четырехъядерном процессоре что-то типа

```
4794 1815494
```

Меняем на атомарные - и получаем (с заметной задержкой)

```
1 4000002
```

Все ясно?

Comment: хм, да, спасибо, только по поводу теории бы еще...

Comment: Реализация атомарных типов, насколько я помню, в стандарте не прописана. Для обеспечения атомарности могут использоваться самые разные варианты - критические разделы, мьютексы, специфические команды процессора - т.е. все, что угодно, что не даст прервать выполняемую операцию и переключиться на другой поток. Конкретная реализация зависит от компилятора, операционной системы, аппаратного обеспечения...

Comment: Можно сделать атомарный доступ и самостоятельно - проще всего с помощью мьютексов. При каждой операции с переменной захватывать мьютекс, после - отпускать.

Comment: ну я так понимаю атомарные операции были созданы как раз чтобы с помощью мьютексов не блочить т.к. очень тяжеловесно... наверно реализовывать атомарные операции через мьютекс слишком глупо

Comment: Вас интересует какой-то конкретный компилятор/платформа/процессор? Я написал возможные варианты в общем случае, ни в коем случае не говоря, что вот именно так оно и делается. Когда писал о мьютексах - упомянул *проще всего*, а не эффективнее всего :) По большому счету, программиста на C++ эта реализация волновать не должна...

Comment: ну gcc б и linux) интересно ж все-таки

Comment: Тогда - благо, gcc - открытый - смотрите исходники, как это реализовано.

Comment: а нет ли туториала по этому делу какого?

Comment: К слову о тяжеловесности - см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673706/%d0%90%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8-vc-2015

Comment: зачем вы тему то удалили?) норм темка была

Comment: @Abyx, а есть тогда нормальная инфа про atomic и mutex? сравнение  там и т.д.